# How can I create multiple users on multiple VMs using Ansible win_user?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-inventory, winrm

I want to create 3 Users for each of the 40 VMs using Ansible.
VM IP will be entered in inventory.

looks like

> ```
> VM1 : User1, User2, User3
> VM2 : User4, User5, User6
> VM3 : User7, User8, User9
> .....
> ```

```yaml
- hosts: win10
  tasks:
  - name: Create new htuser01
    win_user:
      name: htuser01
      password: Demopass123
      groups:
        - Users
        - Remote Desktop Users
      update_password: always
      password_never_expires: yes
  - name: Create new htuser02
    win_user:
      name: htuser02
      password: Demopass123
      groups:
        - Users
        - Remote Desktop Users
      update_password: always
      password_never_expires: yes
  - name: Create new htuser03
    win_user:
      name: htuser03
      password: Demopass123
      groups:
        - Users
        - Remote Desktop Users
      update_password: always
      password_never_expires: yes
```

The code above causes all VMs to create the same user name.
Is there a way to create 3 different users for each VM?

Comment: could you show how are implemented the variables VM1,VM2.... in your inventory..its not clear...how do you do the link between VM1, VM2, and their respectives hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References to read:

- [Building your Ansible inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)
- [Ansible loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

---

Given the following `test_inventory.yml`

```yaml
---
win10:
  hosts:
    vm1:
      system_users:
        - user1
        - user2
        - user3
    vm2:
      system_users:
        - user4
        - user5
        - user6
    vm3:
      system_users:
        - user7
        - user8
        - user9
```

the following `test_playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: inventory and loop demo
  hosts: win10
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Fake creating a user
      vars:
        demo_msg:
          - I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters
          - "win_user:"
          - "  name: '{{ item }}'"
          - "  password: Demopass123"
          - "  groups:"
          - "    - Users"
          - "    - Desktop Users"
          - "  update_password: always"
          - "  password_never_expires: yes"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ demo_msg }}"
      loop: "{{ system_users }}"
```

gives

```
$ ansible-playbook -i test_inventory.yml test_playbook.yml 

PLAY [inventory and loop demo] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Fake creating a user] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vm1] => (item=user1) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user1'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=user4) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user4'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}
ok: [vm1] => (item=user2) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user2'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=user5) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user5'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=user7) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user7'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}
ok: [vm1] => (item=user3) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user3'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}
ok: [vm2] => (item=user6) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user6'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=user8) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user8'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}
ok: [vm3] => (item=user9) => {
    "msg": [
        "I would play a task to create a win user with the following parameters",
        "win_user:",
        "  name: 'user9'",
        "  password: Demopass123",
        "  groups:",
        "    - Users",
        "    - Desktop Users",
        "  update_password: always",
        "  password_never_expires: yes"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
vm1                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm2                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
vm3                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```